# Google Big Query gives Cannot Access Field page on a value with type ARRAY

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working on getting the qulifiedVisitor count. the qulifiedVisitor will be the user who searched 'apple' on the website.

but I am getting this Error:

```
Cannot access filed page on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64,timeITN64, time64,..>>
```

I tried the method that other people provided before, such as using UNNEST(hits), or exist(). However, it still not working.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts.

[Screenshot of the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADJDG.png).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS QualifiedVisitors
FROM `dataset.tablename`, UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE hits.page.pagePath = '/apple';
```

The important part is aliasing the result of `UNNEST`. In the screenshot that you shared, you are missing an alias, so `hits.page.pagePath` still refers to the original `hits` column rather than the unnested one.

Edit: If the intention is to compute totals where at least one of the entries in `hits` has a `pagePath` of `'/apple'`, you may want to use an `EXISTS` clause rather than flattening the array at the outer scope. For example,

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS QualifiedVisitors,
  SUM(totals.pageViews) AS TotalViews
FROM `dataset.tablename`
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hit
  WHERE hit.page.pagePath = '/apple');
```

Comment: another question if you don't mind. I also interested in finding the count of page views for people searched for apple. so I just change the query by using sum(totals.pageviews) and keep the rest of query same. but it seems not working well.

Comment: Are you getting the same error about accessing a field of an array? Instead you may need to do something like `SUM((SELECT SUM(pageviews) FROM UNNEST(totals))`.

Comment: Hi Elliott, Thank you for your reply. i tried to select sum(totals.pageviews) from `table`, unnest(totals) where hits.page.pagepath='apple'
but I got an error code "Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRUCT<visits INT64, hits INT64, pageviews INT64, ...>"

Comment: Hi Elliott, i tried your method. but i get way more TotalViews than GA's  TotalViews. i also need the data information, so i added the date in select and group by. but still, way more results.

Comment: Can you maybe post a separate question with the query that you are trying and explain how the output is different? It's hard to help through a comment chain.

Comment: here is the new question: mhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129382/google-big-query-page-view-count-does-not-match-with-ga-page-view-count. I really appreciate your help