# Google Big Query page view count does not match with GA page view count

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the count of total.pageviews of people go through the booking page on website. Here is my query.

```
SELECT  sum( totals.pageviews ) AS Searches,Date
FROM `table*`
WHERE exists (
select 1 from unnest(hits) as hits
where hits.page.pagePath ='booking'
) 
and date='20161109'
GROUP BY DATE
```

But I got way more results than what i got from Google Analytics. 
Big query result: around 1M
GA: around 300,000
This is the GA page that I am trying to match with

[GA result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wATvO.png)
[image: GA screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution solve this problem:

SELECT  count(totals.pageviews) AS Searches,Date
FROM `table`, UNNEST(hits) as hits
WHERE hits.page.pagePath ='/booking' and hits.type='PAGE'
GROUP BY DATE

Hope this answer can help other people.

Answer (score 0):

After looking a bit more into Google Analytics data, I think that you actually want to count entries in `hits` that match the condition directly instead of relying on `totals.pageViews`. The problem is that `totals.pageViews` represents the number of distinct pages visited within a particular session (if I'm using the correct terminology), which includes pages that don't match your filter. I think you want something like this instead:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS Searches,
  Date
FROM `table*`, UNNEST(hits) AS hit
WHERE hit.page.pagePath = 'booking';
```

This counts the matched pages directly, and will hopefully give the expected numbers.

Comment: Hi Elliott, I tried the new logic, but it still gives me over 1M records. I attached a photo of the GA screen shot. The pageview is the measure that I want to match my Big query data with

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT
  date,
  COUNT(*) AS Searches,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) as PageViews
FROM `table*`, UNNEST(hits) AS hit
WHERE hit.page.pagePath = 'booking'
AND hit.hitNumber = 1
GROUP BY date
```

Searches - number of sessions started with booking page as an entry point to website;
PageViews - number of pageviews in those (above) sessions

> I would like to have total(totals.pageview ) for the booking page on
>   the website. how many times that the booking page has been viewed

First - `total(totals.pageview)` - doesn't help in identifying what really you need as you are assuming that using total.pageviews field is correct, which seems is not - at least based on the rest of your wording

Secondly, if to assume that what you need is  - count of pageviews of the booking page on the website - the only reasonable answer is below

```
SELECT
  date,
  COUNT(1) AS BookingPageViews
FROM `table*`, UNNEST(hits) AS hit
WHERE hit.page.pagePath = 'booking'
GROUP BY date
```

Finally, if you still getting numbers different from what you expect - you need to revisit your what actually you are looking for. It might be that the number that you see in GA represents metric that is different from what you think it represents. This is the only explanation I would see

Comment: Hi Mikhail, Thank you for your reply. However, I still cannot get BigQuery data to match with the GA data on the pageview. Would you mind explaining the logic behind of hits.hitNumber=1? I know that it's the sequenced hits number. if we set up to 1, then we only get hit first within that session. In this way, now I get way low number than GA. I also attached a screen shot of how I get the pageview in GA. Any thoughts?

Comment: in your question you are asking for pageviews of people which came through the booking page. so you need to see not just for page being a part of path but rather being first page - thus  - hit.hitNumber = 1. hope this helps

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't make it clear before. I would like to have total(totals.pageview ) for the booking page on the website. how many times that the booking page has been viewed.