# Google BigQuery Date(String format) failed to convert/cast as Date

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to convert/cast the date in the big query into date format. My query is like this:

```
SELECT CAST(t.date AS date)
FROM `table` t;
```

But I got an Error code of `Invalid date:'20151108'`. it gave me different error date when I run the query. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', t.date) FROM table t
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! I have another question related to big query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129382/google-big-query-page-view-count-does-not-match-with-ga-page-view-count/41129672#41129672 if you have time, please take a look. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I am new to stackoverflow, so i was not able to vote your answer up yesterday. I only had 13 reputations by yesterday. but now, i have 15. i can vote up your answer. Thank you so much for the help.